# Calcular a diferença de horas sem informar a data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tentando calcular a diferença entre duas horas.
Porém não gostaria de informar as datas.
Gostaria de saber por exemplo que entre 23:00 até 01:00 se passaram 120 minutos.

O que eu tentei fazer e consegui algo parecido foi assim porém tive que informar as datas:

```
DECLARE @antes DATETIME = '2016-10-20 23:00:00.000';

DECLARE @depois DATETIME = '2016-10-21 01:00:00.000';


SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, @antes, @depois)) + 'H'
        + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @antes, @depois) % 60), 2) + ':'
        + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(SECOND, @antes, @depois) % 60), 2);
```

Comment: O SQL Server tem um tipo `time` que talvez atenda ao que você deseja: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está trabalhando com datas diferentes e querendo fazer os cálculos apenas com as horas.
Considerando o problema em questão, considerando suas palavras:

> Gostaria de saber por exemplo que entre 23:00 até 01:00 se passaram
> 120 minutos.

Fiz um exemplo que está disponibilizado no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3db94a/3) e demonstrado abaixo.
Logo após a demonstração da consulta, sugiro a criação e utilização de uma consulta customizada.

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE hora_sem_data (
    codigo int NOT NULL,
    horaInicial varchar(5) NULL,
    horaFinal varchar(5) NULL
);

INSERT INTO hora_sem_data (codigo,horaInicial,horaFinal) VALUES
     (1,'23:00','01:00'),
     (2,'03:00','02:00'),
     (3,'02:00','03:00');
```

**Consulta 1**:

```
Select *,
IIF (cast(horaFinal as time) < cast(horaInicial as time), 
         DATEDIFF(MINUTE, cast(horaInicial as datetime), DateAdd(day, 1, cast(horaFinal as datetime))), 
         DATEDIFF(MINUTE, cast(horaInicial as datetime), cast(horaFinal as datetime))
         )  minutos_passados
from hora_sem_data hsd
```

**[Resultado](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3db94a/3/0)**:

| codigo | horaInicial | horaFinal | minutos_passados |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23:00 | 01:00 | 120 |
| 2 | 03:00 | 02:00 | 1380 |
| 3 | 02:00 | 03:00 | 60 |

### Explicando a função IIF Utilizada:

A Função **IIF**:
Sintaxe: `IIF( boolean_expression, true_value, false_value )`
A função **IIF** está verificando se a hora final é menor que a hora inicial, se essa verificação for verdadeira, então **trata-se de datas de dias diferentes** tornando necessário converter os campos por meio da função `cast`, transformando-os em `datetime` para podermos utilizar as  funções `DateDiff` e `DateAdd` em seguida.
Visto que a primeira expressão será retornada quando a expressão de verificação for verdadeira, foi utilizada a função `DateAdd` para adicionar 1 dia a `horaFinal` tornando-a assim uma "hora final" possível de ser utilizada para calcular a diferença, conforme o trecho `DATEDIFF(MINUTE, cast(horaInicial as datetime), DateAdd(day, 1, cast(horaFinal as datetime)))` que representa o `true_value` da função IFF.
Caso o resultada da *boolean_expression* retorne *false*, siginifica que as horas devem ser consideradas como **sendo horas do mesmo dia**, então temos o trecho `DATEDIFF(MINUTE, cast(horaInicial as datetime), cast(horaFinal as datetime))` sendo executado.

Caso queira ler mais sobre as funções do *sqlserver* utilizadas, poderá consultar no site da microsoft [IIF](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [DateDiff](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) e [DateAdd](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

### Utilizando uma função customizada:

Considerei a possibilidade de informar dois tempos '23:00' e '01:00', sendo o primeiro parâmetro o tempo inicial e o segundo o tempo final. Quando o tempo final for aparentemente **menor** que o tempo inicial, como ocorre no exemplo, significará que deve considerar que esse tempo final refere-se ao dia posterior, devendo converter as variáveis para `datetime` para realizar os cálculos utilizando as funções DateDiff e DateAdd. conforme demonstrado nessa sugestão de função:

```
create function getMinutos(@antes time, @depois time)
Returns int
Begin
    DECLARE @antesDateTime datetime = Cast(@antes as datetime);
    DECLARE @depoisDateTime datetime = Cast(@depois as datetime);
    DECLARE @Result int;

    SELECT @Result =
    IIF (@depoisDateTime < @antesDateTime, 
         DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @antesDateTime, DateAdd(day, 1, @depoisDateTime)), 
         DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @antesDateTime, @depoisDateTime)
         ) 
    Return  @Result   
End;
```

**Utilizando a função em uma consulta SQL:**

```
Select *, dbo.getMinutos(cast(horaInicial as time), cast(horaFinal as time) ) minutos_passados
from hora_sem_data hsd
```

**Resultado:**

| codigo | horaInicial | horaFinal | minutos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23:00 | 01:00 | 120 |
| 2 | 03:00 | 02:00 | 1380 |
| 3 | 02:00 | 03:00 | 60 |

Observe que o resultado obtido com a função customizada é igual ao resultado da consulta SQL demonstrado no Fiddle.

**Por quê utilizar uma função customizada?**
Possibilita o reuso de código e torna a consulta SQL mais legível, por exemplo.

**Alguns exemplos de utilização da função de forma isolada:**
**Ao executar:**

```
DECLARE @antes TIME = '23:00';
DECLARE @depois TIME = '01:00';
Select dbo.getMinutos(@antes,@depois) as minutos
```

**Resulta:**

| minutos |
| --- |
| 120 |

Ao executar, serão considerados **dias diferentes**:

```
DECLARE @antes TIME = '03:00';
DECLARE @depois TIME = '02:00';
Select dbo.getMinutos(@antes,@depois) as minutos
```

**Resultado:**

| minutos |
| --- |
| 1380 |

Ao executar, será considerado como sendo horas do **mesmo** dia:

```
DECLARE @antes TIME = '02:00';
DECLARE @depois TIME = '03:00';
Select dbo.getMinutos(@antes,@depois) as minutos
```

**Resultado:**

| minutos |
| --- |
| 60 |

Você precisará ter cuidado com a lógica do negócio, pois se for possível diferença entre horários que se referem a vários dias, precisará fazer ajustes na solução. Acredito que o ideal seria você trabalhar prioritariamente com campos do tipo *datetime*.

Comment: Realizei edição da resposta. Disponibilizei um exemplo no SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Realmente eu não compreendo porque essa resposta foi negativada. O autor do voto contrário poderia por favor explicar o que há de errado com essa resposta?